# How to check data in table on input through ckeditor

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Here i am trying to check the whether the word is present in table tblword or not.Here i am giving an input through ckeditor to check the presence of word in table. And on linkbutton i.e lblviewentry click and if the input word is present in table the label i.e   label2 text should be "found" if word is not present in table label text shound be "not found". 
Now the problem is that even if i enter the word that is present in table label2 text is "not found" the word .Below is what i have done.

Html used

```
 <div>
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl2" BasePath="~/ckkeditor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
 </div>

 <div>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lblviewentry" CssClass="btn btn-primary shadow1" runat="server" OnClick="lblviewentry_Click"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span></asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
```

Code behind linkbutton

```
 protected void lblviewentry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = OJC.GetBadWord(CKEditorControl2.Text);
    if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        label2.Text = "Found";

    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "Not Found";
    }

}
```

Method Used

```
 public DataTable GetBadWord(string Word)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select *from tblword where Word=@Word";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", Word);


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;

}
```

Comment: Try defining the type of the parameter  => cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = Word})

Comment: try changing the Select statement from `WHERE @Word LIKE ...`